# Angularjs Type error:Cannot read property 'GET()' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-resource

In the following code i get a type error as 
`Type error:Cannot read property 'GET()' of undefined`   what ami doing wrong here

**Services**

```
MyApp.factory('Myops', function($resource) {
    return $resource('/projects/:ID/releases/', {
        ID: "@ID"
    }, {
        "update": {
            method: "PUT"
        },
        "create": {
            method: "POST"
        },
        "get": {
            method: "GET"
        }
    });
});
```

**Controller**

```
MyApp.controller("psCtrls", ['$scope', 'Myops', function($scope, Myops) {
    myops = Myops.GET()
    console.log(myops);

}]);
```

update 1:

After the inclusion of My ops this is the error

```
 Error:[$injector:unpr ] Unknown provider :$resource provider<-$resource<-Myops
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is `Myops` dependency not injected properly

```
MyApp.controller("psCtrls",['$scope', 'Myops', function($scope,Myops){

}]);
```

**Update 1:**

include `angular-resource.js`

then include the required dependency in your app in order to use `$resource` service

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',['ngResouce']);
```

**Update 2**

Your resource get call should be `.get` instead of `.GET()`

```
Myops.get().then(function(data){
   console.log(data);
})
```

Comment: are you sure you inject angular-resource with `ngResource` depancdancy in you app

Comment: After doing the above, Now i run into an error as "Type error" undefined is not a function

Comment: did you use .get() instead of .GET()

Comment: Yes i used get and it is working now.. But why can i uset GET()

Comment: get, update, save, delete & put are predefined method of $resource service, you need to look at https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_11

Answer (score 2):

You need to include your `Myops` service as following:

```
MyApp.controller("psCtrls",['$scope', 'Myops',function($scope,Myops)
{
    myops = Myops.GET()
     console.log(myops);
}]);
```

Based on your updated question: it seems like you didn't include `ngResource` in your application, it didn't come with AngularJs. So, you need to manually include it:

```
<script src="angular-resource.js">
```

Using:

- Google CDN
  e.g. `//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/X.Y.Z/angular-resource.js`
- Bower
  `bower install angular-resource`

Then, inject it in your app:

```
angular.module('app', ['ngResource']);
```

Comment: @Rajeev still not injecting it the right way, check carefully the answers!

Comment: Now i run into an error as "Type error" undefined is not a function

Comment: @Rajeev, you have to use `Myops.get()` instead of `Myops.GET()` as @pankajparkar said.

Answer (score 1):

Myops is not being injected. Change it to

```
...
MyApp.controller("psCtrls",['$scope', 'Myops', function($scope,Myops)
...
```